# Talend Connectivity with Azure Sql Server

Tags: azure-sql-database, talend

I am trying to connect to Azure SQL server using Talend Open Studio (BD edition). Since there is no direct component to connect with Azure SQL server. Need some help on how to connect with Azure Sql Server via Talend.

Comment: thanks i was able to connect the Azure SQL Server.

Comment: use tJDBC connector and one external jars is required <sqljdc4.jar > to connect Azure SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

*From OP's comment:*

To connect to Azure you have to do the following:

- Use *tJDBC* connector
- One external jar is required `sqljdc4.jar`

Thats all to to connect Azure SQL Server.